Setting up a Laravel project with a different user table
I'm creating a laravel project, and have been trying to set it up using an already existing user table.
I have this Oracle table called usuarios, and this is the table I want to use.
I was able to make the Auth::login work inside the login function, the Auth::check returns true.
But when I try to access the landing page it just goes back to the login page (this only happens if I load the auth middleware in the route). If I don't load the auth middleware, the Auth::login doesn't work inside the landing page controller.
My auth controller:
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Models\User;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login'); // Create a login view in resources/views/auth
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'LOGIN' => 'required',
            'SENHA' => 'required',
        ]);
        
        $hashedPassword = md5($request->SENHA);
        
        $user = User::where('LOGIN', $request->LOGIN)
            ->where('SENHA', $hashedPassword)
            ->first();

        if ($user) {
            Auth::login($user);
            
            Log::info('User logged in', ['user' => $user]);
            
            return redirect()->intended('landing-page');
        }
        
        return back()->withErrors([
            'LOGIN' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
        ]);
    }
    
}

my landing-page controller
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;


class LandingPage extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        Log::info('Auth user', ['user' => Auth::user()]);
        $user = Auth::user();

        return view('landing-page', ['user' => $user]);
    }
}

my routes:
Route::get('/login', [AuthController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login');
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:web'] ], function(){
    Route::get('/landing-page', [LandingPage::class, 'index'])->name('landing-page');
});
});

my User.php
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = "news.usuarios";
    protected $primaryKey = 'LOGIN';

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->SENHA;
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'LOGIN',
        'SENHA',

    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'SENHA',
    ];
}


parts of my auth.php:
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

       
    ],

I thought it could be a session problem, but the sessions are stored alright in the sessions folder, and when I get and set a session with some info, I can retrieve it just fine.
I know it's not a good practice to use another table as the auth table, but the company I work for already has another ERP going on, and it would be nice if I could keep the user handling in just one service.
I saw another question similar to mine, Laravel using a different users table returns 419 page expired. But what is suggested there doesn't work for me.

I strongly suggest you to try to follow the path here:
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers
it will make your life much easier to maintain and extend later.
You can also check here https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/authentication#the-user-provider-contract what to implement and witch methods you need.
Try implementing it better if not now then a tech debt for later because if you need cleaner code proper isolation or role and permission and ... later you will be in a pickle with this, and you need again to refactor.
If you have time, do it properly, read the guard implementation in Laravel docs and Authenticables too and do it.
Answer:
But saying that for the sake of solving your problem, just use this in AuthController
I wanted to use Auth::attempt, but it needs password and your table does not have password and I did not want to extend this to map password to your SENHA so for now this will do the job for you:
just replace if ($user) with if (Auth::loginUsingId($user->LOGIN))
// skipping request input and validation

        $user = User::where('LOGIN', $request->LOGIN)
            ->where('SENHA', $hashedPassword)
            ->first();

        if (Auth::loginUsingId($user->LOGIN)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            Log::info('User logged in', ['user' => $user]);

            return redirect()->intended('landing-page');
        }

// other part of the code

Why? attempt, loginUsingId and etc., actually start to do the whole thing of logging in and setting session and use set the user model etc. for you, but just Auth::login() sets the user so you can use that for setting the different user if needed, but you can't authenticate with login https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/authentication#authenticate-a-user-instance
If you need to set an existing user instance as the currently authenticated user
In this case, you didn't have it (as the currently authenticated user not exists) so you just set a user, but it is not authenticated against application but this instance of class, now with loginUsingId it will authenticate too.
Again, your code has a lot of room for cleaning and refinement like request handling also no need to web.auth this middleware not exists at all and because web.php is already using web middleware group, just use auth middleware instead of web.auth on the path that you want to protect.
Document better the user provider too.
I'll let it go now. Hope at least gives you some idea for the next step.
